# form valid method not exist in mvc4 validations

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

We are trying to test a form validation in java script in an mvc4 web project. We are using the jQuery Validation Plugin 1.8.1. When we teste the form validation with the following code:

```
$('#theForm').submit(function(event) {
           if (!$('#theForm').valid()) {
           ....
```

We get the following error when call the valid() function:

> - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'valid'

Why the form element doesn’t have the valid function if in all the examples for validation forms for mvc projects they always use this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. Just because I was referencing jquery two times.

Don’t do this because jquery gets confuse.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$("#theForm").validate()` instead of `$('#theForm').valid()`

```
 $("#myform").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
  }
 });
```

Comment: Thank you but with the validate method I get the same error. It seams that my problem was because I was referencing jquery two times.